# Jboss 4.2.3 - high load on one CPU out of 8

Tags: jboss, ajp

we are running Jboss 4.2.3 on Amazon AWS machine with 8 cores (CPUs)
under load we see that there is a single thread taking massive load on just one CPU, while the other are almost idle. (other threads are distributed on all CPUs)

we see it using top.

we are using an AJP connector, connected to an httpd instance.

could it be the AJP connector thread? or anything else? some sort of threads manager thread?

any info will be appreciated.

Comment: after playing with the JBOSS for a while, i see that GC is running at that stage:
1692.480: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 579840K->48659K(1159616K)] [PSOldGen: 3478911K->3478911K(3478912K)] 4058751K->3527571K(4638528K) [PSPermGen: 102713K->102713K(262144K)], 8.3541710 secs] [Times: user=8.37 sys=0.00, real=8.35 secs]

and doesn't finish running even after one hour.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably also post the OS and JVM information. The problem might be that your JVM is not using all the other CPU's because it's probably not optimized for multi-core/cpu architecture. JBoss 4.x is definitely not optimized for it but JBoss AS 7 is designed to leverage the multi-core architecture.

Comment: we are using openJdk with debian linux

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.7) (6b18-1.8.7-2~squeeze1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)

moving to Jboss AS 7 is a costly migration at the moment